# How to slice pd.dataframe several times without using for_loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Question

- I would like to slice the dataframe (`customer_df`) based on other two dataframes (`start_time_df` and `end_time_df`) without using for loop.

  - The goal is to know which customers are handled by the certain employee.
  - `customer_df`: showing the names of customers, locations and the time where and when they bought products.
  - `start_time_df` & `end_time_df`: A time sheet of the certain employee's start and end time of work.
- I have managed to do this using for loop, but if the dataframe gets large, it would take much time using for loop. As such I am looking for how to do this without using the for loop.
- Example and my solution(for loop ver.) is provided below.

### Example

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

customer_df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['A','B','C','A','D','E','K','A','D','F','P','J'],
                            'location': ['NY','TX','NY','UT','MA','NV','NY','TX','NY','UT','MA','NV']},
                           index = [datetime(2020,5,1,9), datetime(2020,5,1,11), datetime(2020,5,1,12),
                                    datetime(2020,5,1,18), datetime(2020,5,2,5), datetime(2020,5,2,10), 
                                    datetime(2020,5,2,19), datetime(2020,5,3,2), datetime(2020,5,3,10),
                                    datetime(2020,5,3,18), datetime(2020,5,4,20), datetime(2020,5,4,22)])

start_time_df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time':[datetime(2020,5,1,8), datetime(2020,5,2,8), datetime(2020,5,3,5)]})

end_time_df = pd.DataFrame({'end_time':[datetime(2020,5,1,17), datetime(2020,5,2,17), datetime(2020,5,3,20)]})

customer_df
>>>                  customer  location
2020-05-01 09:00:00      A        NY
2020-05-01 11:00:00      B        TX
2020-05-01 12:00:00      C        NY
2020-05-01 17:00:00      A        UT
2020-05-02 05:00:00      D        MA
2020-05-02 10:00:00      E        NV
2020-05-02 19:00:00      K        NY
2020-05-03 02:00:00      A        TX
2020-05-03 08:00:00      D        NY
2020-05-03 15:00:00      F        UT
2020-05-04 20:00:00      P        MA
2020-05-04 22:00:00      J        NV
```

- I have managed to slice the `customer_df` using for loop, but is there a way to do this without using for loop?

```py
sliced_df_list = []  # to store slices

start_time_series = start_time_df.loc[:,'start_time']
end_time_series = end_time_df.loc[:,'end_time']

for start_time, end_time in zip(start_time_series, end_time_series):
    sliced_df_list.append(customer_df.loc[start_time:end_time,:])
    
pd.concat(sliced_df_list)
>>>                  customer   location
2020-05-01 09:00:00      A         NY
2020-05-01 11:00:00      B         TX
2020-05-01 12:00:00      C         NY
2020-05-02 10:00:00      E         NV
2020-05-03 10:00:00      D         NY
2020-05-03 18:00:00      F         UT
```

Answer (score 0):

As a preparatory step, compute:

```
indTpl = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(start_time_df.start_time,
    end_time_df.end_time, closed='neither').to_tuples()
```

It is a counterpart of:

```
zip(start_time_series, end_time_series)
```

but you avoid explicit creation of *start_time_series* and *end_time_series*.

Then, to get the result, run:

```
result = pd.concat([ customer_df.loc[slice(*it)] for it in indTpl ])
```

This code runs about 25 % faster than yours.
For bigger source DataFrames the difference can be more apparent.
Check on your own.

Comment: What does the `slice` mean, located at the last code block? Is it a method provided by Python?

Comment: Can you also explain why using the asterisk before the variable `it`, at the last cod block, please?

Comment: *slice* is a slice constructor (lower limit, upper limit).
And as far as the star before *it* is concerned:
Note that *it* is actually a 2-tuple (both limits of the current time interval).
So this star is used to expand this tuple into both slice borders.
It is worth that you searched the Web for *Python argument expansion*.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, your solution does not cover the case in which employee time does not cover the working time in `customer_df` so my suggestion will cover that:

Here my suggestion:

(1) put start_time and end_time in one DataFrame called `start_end`

```
start_end=start_time_df
start_end['end_time']=end_time_df['end_time']
```

(2) initailze DataFrame `sliced_df_list` and add `date_time` to work with later:

```
sliced_df_list=customer_df
sliced_df_list['date_time']= sliced_df_list.index
```

(3) Add the column `emp` that will hold the employees' list existed in working time.

```
sliced_df_list['emp']= sliced_df_list['date_time'].apply(lambda x: start_end[(start_end['start_time']<=x) & (start_end['end_time']>=x)].index)
```

(4) Store only the first employee in the list or say NaN if there is not an employee covers the working time

```
sliced_df_list['emp']=sliced_df_list['emp'].apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) if len(x)>0 else None)
```

Finally, print the results

```
print(sliced_df_list)
```

```
                    customer location           date_time  emp
2020-05-01 09:00:00        A       NY 2020-05-01 09:00:00  0.0
2020-05-01 11:00:00        B       TX 2020-05-01 11:00:00  0.0
2020-05-01 12:00:00        C       NY 2020-05-01 12:00:00  0.0
2020-05-01 18:00:00        A       UT 2020-05-01 18:00:00  NaN
2020-05-02 05:00:00        D       MA 2020-05-02 05:00:00  NaN
2020-05-02 10:00:00        E       NV 2020-05-02 10:00:00  1.0
2020-05-02 19:00:00        K       NY 2020-05-02 19:00:00  NaN
2020-05-03 02:00:00        A       TX 2020-05-03 02:00:00  NaN
2020-05-03 10:00:00        D       NY 2020-05-03 10:00:00  2.0
2020-05-03 18:00:00        F       UT 2020-05-03 18:00:00  2.0
2020-05-04 20:00:00        P       MA 2020-05-04 20:00:00  3.0
2020-05-04 22:00:00        J       NV 2020-05-04 22:00:00  3.0
```

now `sliced_df_list` hold employee number in `emp` column, and you can deal with this data frame as you want through sorting, grouping.... etc ***without loops, and covering any missing employee working period***

Modification and more clarification will be given upon the comments below

***Based on Comments***

In order to get the same result of your code

```
sliced_df_list.dropna(inplace=True) # dromp all rows contains NaN (one slice)
a=sliced_df_list.drop(['emp','date_time'],axis=1)
print(a)
```

```
                    customer location
2020-05-01 09:00:00        A       NY
2020-05-01 11:00:00        B       TX
2020-05-01 12:00:00        C       NY
2020-05-02 10:00:00        E       NV
2020-05-03 10:00:00        D       NY
2020-05-03 18:00:00        F       UT
2020-05-04 20:00:00        P       MA
2020-05-04 22:00:00        J       NV
```

***In addition***
if we want to make a separate slice for each emplopyee, so we use `groupby`:

```
sliced_df_list=list(sliced_df_list.groupby('emp')) # slicing based on emp
```

print(sliced_df_list)

```
[(0.0,
                      customer location           date_time  emp
  2020-05-01 09:00:00        A       NY 2020-05-01 09:00:00  0.0
  2020-05-01 11:00:00        B       TX 2020-05-01 11:00:00  0.0
  2020-05-01 12:00:00        C       NY 2020-05-01 12:00:00  0.0),
 (1.0,
                      customer location           date_time  emp
  2020-05-02 10:00:00        E       NV 2020-05-02 10:00:00  1.0),
 (2.0,
                      customer location           date_time  emp
  2020-05-03 10:00:00        D       NY 2020-05-03 10:00:00  2.0
  2020-05-03 18:00:00        F       UT 2020-05-03 18:00:00  2.0),
 (3.0,
                      customer location           date_time  emp
  2020-05-04 20:00:00        P       MA 2020-05-04 20:00:00  3.0
  2020-05-04 22:00:00        J       NV 2020-05-04 22:00:00  3.0)]
```

Looking forward to knowing the difference in performance compared with the loop method.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, but since it is just a certain employee's working time, the time ranges made by `start_time_df` and `end_time_df` do not need to cover all the customers or working time specified in the `customer_df`. As such, it should be the case that `sliced_df_list` covers only a subset of `customer_df`

Comment: Yes, anyhow you will find the uncovered customer visit time with the NaN values in `emp` column.

Comment: Finally I found the keyword of my question, which is 'multi-range indexing on pd.DataFrame'. I appreciate your answer but can you answer my question from this perspective? I mean, to slice a dataframe with a multiple datetime ranges...

Comment: if you use 'multi-range indexing' you will find slices include period with no employees exist - and if you get a satisfactory answer, put it among the answers.